# npm not installing the versions I'd expect

Tags: npm

I created a .NET Core 2 Angular application using the template in visual studio 2017 and everything was hunky-dory.

At some point I decided I wanted to upgrade to the new HttpClientModule in Angular 4.3, so in my package.json I changed

```
"@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
"@angular/common": "4.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
"@angular/core": "4.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
"@angular/http": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
"@angular/router": "4.2.5",
```

to

```
"@angular/animations": "4.3",
"@angular/common": "4.3",
"@angular/compiler": "4.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3",
"@angular/core": "4.3",
"@angular/forms": "4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.3",
"@angular/router": "4.3",
```

I deleted my node_modules folder and ran npm install, and the output shows

```
+-- @angular/animations@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/common@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/compiler@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@4.2.5 
| `-- minimist@1.2.0 
+-- @angular/core@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/forms@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/http@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/platform-browser@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/platform-server@4.2.5 
+-- @angular/router@4.2.5
```

I'm far from an expert with npm so I'm assuming I made some noob mistake in either my usage or my expectations.  Can anyone advise?

Comment: Do you have a [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) ? They are automatically generated since npm v5.

Comment: No, I don't seem to have one.  I think it was an issue with how I was using update vs. install.  I did manage to get the intended versions to install but then ended up with some other dependency related errors :(

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have `package-lock.json`, I would suggest to find and delete `npm-shrinkwrap.json` in your project folder and run `npm install` once again.